# Avoiding \hbox of long citations going over page margins

Tags: bibliographies, packages, highlighting

I am using the `soul` package to highlight text, some of which includes long citations. I'm using `\hbox` to get around the compilation errors so far, but this command is terrible for long citations!

Here is the gist of my text:

`\hl{Some text here \hbox{\parencite[see, e.g.,][]{citation1, citation2, citation3, citation4}.}`

And the result is:
[image]

So far, I have tried the following:

- Using the `microtype` package
- Using `sloppy` commands on the entire document and on the paragraph
- Rewriting text to fit, which you can see here (this circumvented the annoying issue of the hbox starting on a new line, which was terrible since "dynamic representations" was previously on a new line).

Any other ideas on how to deal with this? Or better yet, is there a friendlier highlighting package out there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If using LuaLaTeX is an option you can use the `lua-ul` package instead of `soul`. With that you don't need the nested `\hbox`es at all and things should just work™.

Comment: Alternatively, if `lua-ul` is no option, the `ulem` package can highlight as well and is more stable than `soul`, the downside is, that it doesn't allow automatic hyphenation and only is line breakable at word boundaries (but `\-` for manual hyphenation works with it).

Comment: An `\hbox` will never break at the end of a line.  If it's important to keep everything inside that box "local", wrap it instead in `\begingroup ... \endgroup`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the `\hbox` is most likely necessary to get `\parencite` working inside of `soul`, using `\begingroup ...\endgroup` will not work for that purpose.

Comment: @Skillmon -- Oh, dear.  Never needed to use that feature of `soul`.  Unfortunate limitation.